# Ajax load data not showing data in Bootstrap popover

Tags: php, html, ajax

Bootstrap popover is only showing a blank popover as shown below
[image: Bootstrap Popover]

I checked my fetch_cart.php and its working as below
[image]

Below is how my ajax looks, not sure what im missing there, have trying changing ids, looks like the #cart_details is not retuning and data and i can't seem to figure it out. Would really appreciate your help on this.
`

```
`   function load_cart_data()
    {
        $.ajax({
          url:"fetch_cart.php",
          method:"POST",
          dataType:"json",
          success:function(data)
          {
          $('#cart_details').html(data.cart_details);
        $('.total_price').text(data.total_price);
        $('.badge').text(data.total_item);
        }
    });
    }

    $('#cart-popover').popover({
        html : true,
        container: 'body',
        content:function(){
          return $('#cart_pop_details').html();
      }
  });`
```

And here is my HTML code where the data should be returned or rather popover
`

```
<div id="cart_pop_details" style="display: none">
        <span id="cart_details"></span>
        <div align="right">
          <a href="checkout.php" class="btn btn-primary" id="check_out_cart">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Check out
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="clear_cart">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Clear
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```